# Risk factors per disease

Tags: data-request, medical

I am looking for a data set on risk factors for diseases as many following fields as possible:

- list of risk factors per disease
- references for each risk factor (i.e., in which research study X was shown To be a risk factor for disease Y.)

I'm also interested in negative results, i.e., results showing that X is not a risk factor for Y.